# Trouble with Prometheus metrics (Adapter and metricsQuery)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, prometheus-adapter

Original problem. I would like to have a Kubernetes cluster with at least 2 nodes with zero GPU consumption. If a job is coming and takes one node, then autoscaler should create another spare node.

I found out that I can rely on `DCGM_FI_DEV_GPU_UTIL` metrics. If `DCGM_FI_DEV_GPU_UTIL == 0` then the node is in "idle" mode. In PromQL I can just write `count(DCGM_FI_DEV_GPU_UTIL == 0)` and get the number of "idle" nodes.

However, I do not understand how to write metricsQuery in Prometheus Adapter config. All examples that I found are about

```
(sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[1m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
```

However, I need something like `count(<<.Series>> == 0)`, but this does not work. Any idea how I can get this metrics for HPA  which indicates the number of nodes with no GPU consumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with [KEDA with the prometheus trigger](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/scalers/prometheus/). It is easy to use and supports PromQL query. The only disadvantage that it is ["average value" scaler](https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues/1881#issuecomment-874562446), but it is not critical in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your jobs are running in Kubernetes Pod. You may have a configuration where only one custom Pod with job can run on a single Node. The first step is to configure your metrics for the Prometheus adapter and it's described quite nicely [here](https://blog.wyrihaximus.net/2021/01/scaling-php-fpm-based-on-utilization-demand-on-kubernetes/). This step will ensure that the Pod is added.

In the second step you need to configure a cluster autoscaler that will add another Node when needed. Cluster autoscaler is dependent on your Kubernetes solution provider (AWS, Azure, GCP...) and should be in their documentation. I personally use [Cluster autoscaler](https://www.kubecost.com/kubernetes-autoscaling/kubernetes-cluster-autoscaler/), [Karpenter](https://karpenter.sh/).

Comment: Thank you. At the moment, I'm stuck with the Prometheus adapter. Not sure why, but this configuration from example does not work in my case: seriesQuery: 
 'DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL{namespace!="",pod_name!=""}' does not work (kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 returns nothing). It starts working for me when I use a different format seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL$"}'. However, I still cannot write metricsQuery. I need a comparison: count(<<.Series>> < 5), but it does not work.

Comment: First of all your query DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL{namespace!="",sub_name!=""} must work in Prometheus - Execute and return results. You add it as a Rule for Prometheus-adapter to the entry - seriesQuery: 'DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL{namespace!="",sub_name!=""}' and then to metricsQuery: 'max(DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL) by (<<.GroupBy>>)'
Finally, you add it to the Kubernetes HPA definition and watch for 2 and start a new Pod (if 1 or 0 - less than 2) that will take up the entire Node. So in the first phase, it will just wait for the Cluster autoscaler to create that Node for it.

Comment: @VitezslavSkacel, first paragraph of your answer contains link to some article and quite vague description. Consider adding at least small paraphrase of what's inside linked material, in case this link is outdated, material removed, etc.

Comment: @VitezslavSkacel, sorry, what is sub_name label and what max function does? In my case this metric returns 0. However, I have one pod with no GPU consumption.
Also, I am not sure why HPA should start a new pod. For example, current metric is 1, target metric is 2. I thought that HPA only works if the current metric is higher than the target one. Then it tries to make the current one make smaller than the target one by creating new pods.

Comment: In that case you can use only seriesQuery: DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL as the prometheus metrics without any other parameters in parentheses. And in metricsQuery: 'max(DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL) by (<<.GroupBy>>)' because the maximum of the set {0} is 0. Max and GroupBy is only used because of the possibility that it will return Series. If the Nodes start getting loaded, it will return 1, 2... and you start more pods by expressing abs(2 - (result of metricsQuery)) is equal to the number of new pods that are needed.

Comment: This bootstrapping is already a matter of the Kubernetes HPA manifest, where the new metrics from prometheus-adapter described above are used. This will be described to you when the new prometheus-adapter metric kicks in via the api with kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/REPLACE_THIS_NAMESPACE/pods/*/DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL" and is mentioned in the linked article.

Comment: Thank you for details. Let me be more specific. I need to have at least 2 "idle" pods (with DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL = 0). For example, there are already 1 "idle" pod and 2 pods with DCGM_FI_DEV_DEC_UTIL = 10. So HPA should create 1 more "idle" pod. According to your expression abs(2 - (result of metricsQuery)) = abs(2 - 10) = 8. But it is required to create just 1 pod rather than 8.

Comment: So it is still not clear, how it should work, unfortunately :( And it is not clear where I should specify the expression that you mentioned abs(2 - (result of metricsQuery)).